# Batch file to open eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to open eclipse at my desired workspace.
So far I managed to make it create a new workspace however I want it to open in an already created one.

All I found was the `-data` command. This is the relevant code line:

```
start "" "%wriver%" -data %envpath%
```

wriver is the path to my wriver ( built on eclipse) executable.
envpath is the path to my workspace.

Comment: So what is wrong with this? -data is correct for the workspace.

Comment: it creates a new workspace and I want it to open an already existing one.

Comment: Specifying the path of an existing workspace to `-data` opens that workspace.